# Changing redux state but also retain some old values of state

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, pass-by-reference

In my React-Redux app, I am changing the redux `state` and it looks something like this

```
state {
    key1: oldVal1
    key2: oldArray1 //The value here is an array
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now when I update the state next time...

```
state {
    key1: newVal1

    //But for key2 I want to keep the value as the same oldArray1
    //Now since that oldArray1 is not anywhere except in the old state, can I do this...?

    key2: state.key2
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So if I do `key2: state.key2` and `state.key2` is an array, will the reference be lost since state is changed and state.key2 won't point to anything?

I just want a rough explanation of how `object/array` references will affect state in redux.

Answer (score 3):

You always want to return a new state -- not mutate your existing state.  You can use the spread operator to return a new state that retains some of the same properties of your old state

```
export default  function(state = {}, action) {
switch(action.type) {
    case WHATEVER_ACTION:
         const newValue = action.payload.value; //assuming this comes from action
         return { ...state, key: newValue };
  }
}
```

This way you update the key you want to update with your new value, but everything you want to leave as is will maintain its old values, as it's spread into the `newState` object.

Comment: So the second time I change state I am returning a new object but it has one of its values it gets from a previous state which is a reference to an array.... That is my true concern

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, the initial array on state is a reference to an array.  So, when you are putting that into you new state, you're just assigning that same array (or reference thereto) to key on a new state.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Redux state is immutable, so first state and second state is two different objects, so you can assign old value to new key, if you use Object.assign or another immutable tool, of course.

```
      switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            key1: action.newVal1,
            key2: state.key1,
          })
```